# JPA 1.0 Hibernate & Derby HashMap with an Enum key usage

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am looking for help in mapping a HashMap, using JPA, which is built like so..  `<NflTeam, Integer>`.  NflTeam is an enum of all the possible NFL Teams. The value for the map is unimportant at this stage.

I have tried, not using any annotation over the hash map field in the entity class, but what I have found is that when I attempt to update the map, I get the following error:

> ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - A truncation error
>   was encountered trying to shrink VARCHAR () FOR BIT DATA '(Binary data
>   value not displayed)' to length 255. 5371 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Could not
>   synchronize database state with session

I have also tried to add the following annotation to the field in the entity class `@ElementCollection`, as I have seen a few places say that this is the annotation use to map hash maps, but I am finding I get the following error when I attempt to map the entity:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a
>   non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements:
>   ie.madden.stats.core.beans.Player.teamsPlayedWithMap

Does anyone know the correct annotation to use in JPA, to map a genericized hashmap (constructed of an )?

Thanks in advance

---

***EDIT::***

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">  <persistence-unit name="MaddenStatsPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>    <class>ie.madden.stats.core.beans.Player</class>    <class>ie.madden.stats.core.beans.Fixture</class>    <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:maddenstats;create=true"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="madden"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="madden"/>
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
     <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="MaddenStats"/>    </properties>  </persistence-unit> </persistence>
```

Secondly here is my entity class for Player where the hashmap is being used:

```
@Entity
public class Player implements IEntityBean
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="id_Gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_Gen", sequenceName="id_Seq")
    private Long playerId;

    private String name;
    private Long played = new Long(0);
    private Long wins = new Long(0);
    private Long losses = new Long(0);
    private Integer winPercentage = new Integer(0);

    private HashMap<NflTeam, Integer> teamsPlayedWithMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

In the sample above I have removed any attempts I have tried for the mapping of the HashMap.

Oh also NflTeam is an enum, which like I have already said is a enum of all the NFL Teams...

Comment: Your questions is very incomplete. Please post relevant portions of your Entity definitions, and a high level table schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA1 does **not** provide support for such a Map. You have to go to implementation specifics. JPA2 does.

Comment: Okay, So I will need to look into seeing if Derby/Hibernate supports JPA 2.   If they do, do you know any resource that could show me the correct mappings for my given problem?